# Debian Wheezy ffmpeg version 1.2.5 and OpenCV

Tags: opencv, ffmpeg, debian

I recently installed "ffmpeg version 1.2.5" from "deb ftp://ftp.deb-multimedia.org wheezy-backports main" on my Debian Wheezy.

I wrote some code with OpenCV and now I get the following error when I try to open a video.

```
[NULL @ 0x21e2ec0] Value 4613937818241073152.000000 for parameter 'thread_type' out of range
[NULL @ 0x21e2ec0] Value -4616189618054758400.000000 for parameter 'request_sample_fmt' out of range
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x282d580] decoding for stream 0 failed
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x282d580] Could not find codec parameters (Video: h264 (avc1 / 0x31637661), 23069 kb/s)
[IMGUTILS @ 0x7ffff1da3fd0] Picture size 0x0 is invalid
[IMGUTILS @ 0x7ffff1da3fe0] Picture size 0x0 is invalid
```

///////  SOLUTION /////////

I speculated the problem started after I added the following two source to my /etc/apt/sources.list file on Debian Wheezy.  I did this procure a newer version of FFMPEG.

deb ftp:// ftp.deb-multimedia . org wheezy main non-free
deb ftp:// ftp.deb-multimedia . org wheezy-backports main

It was then all my code written using the OpenVC started to break.  I had a hunch it was my recent upgrade but not sure until I read the following.

“Make sure proper versions of ffmpeg or gstreamer is installed. Sometimes, it is a headache to work with Video Capture mostly due to wrong installation of ffmpeg/gstreamer.”  ~ http: // opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.org/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_gui/py_video_display/py_video_display.html

[ SOLUTION ]

This search will tell you what installed packages come from Debian Multimedia:

aptitude search '~i ?origin(Unofficial Multimedia Packages)'

And this command removes them:

aptitude purge '~i ?origin(Unofficial Multimedia Packages)'

Remove the deb-multimedia.org repository from the source.list file.  Install FFMPEG and OpenVC and any additional packages that you need, since much was purged from your system during the downgrade.

sudo aptitude install python-opencv  ffmpeg

Comment: Why did you not include your code?

Comment: This is the code.   vc = cv2.VideoCapture(videofilename)

Comment: This is the code.  http://pastebin.com/QjAYKEaL

Comment: It must be ffmpeg.  I read the following.  "Make sure proper versions of ffmpeg or gstreamer is installed. Sometimes, it is a headache to work with Video Capture mostly due to wrong installation of ffmpeg/gstreamer." ~ http://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.org/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_gui/py_video_display/py_video_display.html